# Data is not being stored in core data database

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6

```
NSArray  *theArray = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"myArray"];
for (NSDictionary * dict in theArray) {

    CustomerOrder * newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CustomerOrder"
                                                             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"customer_id"] forKey:@"customer_id"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"ExecutedOrderCount"] forKey:@"executedOrderCount"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"order_id"] forKey:@"order_id"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"outletLatitude"] forKey:@"outletLatitude"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"outletLongitude"] forKey:@"outletLongitude"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_days"] forKey:@"trigger_days"];

    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_end_date"] forKey:@"trigger_end_date"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_from_time"] forKey:@"trigger_from_time"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_no_days"] forKey:@"trigger_no_days"];

    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_radius"] forKey:@"trigger_radius"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_start_date"] forKey:@"trigger_start_date"];
    [newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_to_time"] forKey:@"trigger_to_time"];

    NSLog(@"Log %@", newEntry);

    [SharedAppDelegate saveContext];
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you use newEntry[@"trigger_radius"] = dict[@"trigger_radius"]. It makes your code much more readable. Also, show how you save the context, and show how you know it is not saved (i.e. show your fetching code).

Comment: I have changed [sharedAppDelegate savecontext]to
[newEntry.managedObjectContext save:&err] NSLog(@"error: %@", err.localizedDescription);I have done that's it.I don't know how to fetch .I'm manually checking in sqllite browser which is showing no tables are found. please provide some help.

Comment: Is newEntry maybe nil? What is the output of your log statement? Can you also show the fetching-code? Do you check the BOOL that the save: method returns?

Comment: <CustomerOrder: 0x9114200> (entity: CustomerOrder; id: 0x91f0b10 <x-coredata:///CustomerOrder/t3A6E64B5-C73F-47E1-8813-587C10A732B02> ; data: {
    "customer_id" = 6;
    executedOrderCount = 0;
    "order_id" = 93;
    outletLatitude = "30.8865366";
    outletLongitude = "75.8388698";
    "trigger_days" = 3;
    "trigger_end_date" = "2014-04-30T00:00:00";
    "trigger_from_time" = "19:30:00";
    "trigger_no_days" = 0;
    "trigger_radius" = 416;
    "trigger_start_date" = "2014-03-27T00:00:00";
    "trigger_to_time" = "07:30:00";
})
 error: (null)

Comment: This code: "NSLog(@"error: %@", err.localizedDescription);" should only print out an error (or "null" if not present),yet you show the output of what I suspect it NSLog(@"%@", newEntry). This shows you that a new NSManagedObject was created. For debugging I suggest you replace "[SharedAppDelegate saveContext];" with "NSError * error = nil; if ([newEntry.managedObjectContext save: &error] == NO){NSLog(@"CANNOT SAVE: %@", error); else {NSLog(@"SUCCES, go check the sqlite file")}

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", newEntry)  is giving 
Log <CustomerOrder: 0x10b78f00> (entity: CustomerOrder; id: 0x10b78f40 <x-coredata:///CustomerOrder/tF7EEBCCB-B0BE-40C6-828F-BFC16248BE852> ; data: {
    "customer_id" = 6;
    executedOrderCount = 0;
    "order_id" = 93;
    outletLatitude = "30.8865366";
    outletLongitude = "75.8388698";
    "trigger_days" = 3;
    "trigger_end_date" = "2014-04-30T00:00:00";
    "trigger_from_time" = "19:30:00";
    "trigger_no_days" = 0;
    "trigger_radius" = 416;
    "trigger_start_date" = "2014-03-27T00:00:00";
    "trigger_to_time" = "07:30:00";
})

Comment: this is getting.     SUCCES, go check the sqlite file

Comment: Ok, so that means that you have successfully save your managedObject. It should now be present in the sqlite file.

Comment: ///Users/vishnuemani/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applic‌​ations/4BC11011-F80F-41C7-870A-99F3666E678F/Documents/CoreData.sqlite  this is my sqllite file path.
I'm opening it with sqllite browser ,but still it is showing no tables are found.Do I need to implement anything else

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the wrong simulator (you know, iOS 7, iOS 7.1 then there is 64 bit versions). You know you are looking at the correct one by either checking the mod date of the sqlite file, or resetting the simulator and then checking for which sim in "///Users/vishnuemani/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/" you app is no longer present.

Comment: Is there any other way to check whether the tables are created or not.

Comment: I'm going to the exact path which I'm getting the log that I'have sent you.

Comment: Can you show the code that instantiates and initialises the managedObjectContext?

Comment: In view did load
self.managedObjectContext = SharedAppDelegate.managedObjectContext; I did this.

Comment: I'm fetching data with this method

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"CustomerOrder" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *tmpArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
int count =0;
        for (int i=0; i<tmpArray.count; i++) {
  
        CustomerOrder * record = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:i];

 }
    }

Comment: I can fetch data in that way. but I cannot see that in file.

Comment: Please show the actual code that creates the MOC.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CustomerOrder" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];
NSManagedObject * newEntry =[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    ....


NSError *error;                
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

hope this will help..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSArray  *theArray = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"myArray"];
 for (NSDictionary * dict in theArray) {

//TypeCast here

CustomerOrder* newEntry = (CustomerOrder *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CustomerOrder"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"customer_id"] forKey:@"customer_id"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"ExecutedOrderCount"] forKey:@"executedOrderCount"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"order_id"] forKey:@"order_id"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"outletLatitude"] forKey:@"outletLatitude"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"outletLongitude"] forKey:@"outletLongitude"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_days"] forKey:@"trigger_days"];

[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_end_date"] forKey:@"trigger_end_date"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_from_time"] forKey:@"trigger_from_time"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_no_days"] forKey:@"trigger_no_days"];

[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_radius"] forKey:@"trigger_radius"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_start_date"] forKey:@"trigger_start_date"];
[newEntry setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"trigger_to_time"] forKey:@"trigger_to_time"];

NSLog(@"Log %@", newEntry);

//Save all  
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
// Handle Error
      NSLog(@"Save Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  return NO;
  }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You create entity in `self.managedObjectContext` but for save calls `[SharedAppDelegate saveContext];`

can you try add this code after `NSLog`

```
NSError * err = nil;
[newEntry.managedObjectContext save:&err];

NSLog(@"error: %@", err.localizedDescription);
```

and after loop call save in parent context

```
__weak typeof (self) weakSelf;
[self.managedObjectContext.parentContext performBlock:^(){ [weakSelf.managedObjectContext.parentContext save:NULL] }];
```

Comment: error is getting null.but in database if I check there are no tables created it is showing.

Comment: This is my filepath and i open this in sqllite browser.
///Users/vishnuemani/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/4BC11011-F80F-41C7-870A-99F3666E678F/Documents/CoreData.sqlite

Comment: @user3420042 updated answer, the idea is call save in parent context

Comment: what does this do
__weak typeof (self) weakSelf;
[self.managedObjectContext.parentContext performBlock:^(){ [weakSelf.managedObjectContext.parentContext save:NULL] }];

Comment: in CoreData only __root__ context write changes to persistent storage (file), all nested context commits changes. this code I added call save: in parent context, but with performBlock, because we should not access context from different threads

Comment: My coreData.sqllite file is showing no tables are found. I don't know why.In managed object context entity is saving.

Comment: You don't need a weak block for this, just pass the moc rather than the call to get it. Also, this is only really relevant if the OP is using multi - threaded core data which it doesn't look like he is.